# Redis Log says Connection Reset by Peer

Tags: redis

I am getting the "Connection Reset by Peer" error in Redis Log.

Comment: Please elaborate some more info: Which client do you use to connect to Redis, how frequent the error occurs / what has happened just before the error etc.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576882/redis-timeout-with-predis

Comment: If this is in the server log, doesn't this just mean that the client closed the connection? Is there any 'problem' related to this event?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22connection+reset+by+peer%22+redis

Answer (score 1):

probably your client either timed out or has raised another exception that disconnects the connection before redis was able to write to it. or it has crashed.

either increase your client's timeout, or check the client logs to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to connect to redis before it's fully started, you might get this error from the client.

I fixed it by adding a two-second sleep after starting the container and before trying to connect.  Better would be to wait for some kind of healthy indicator.